# Keyerror in python despite having keyword

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk

I am getting `KeyError:'Fellow'` after running following program despite this keyword exist in the `text4`.

```
  import nltk;
  from nltk.book import *
  cnt = {}
  for word in text4:
       cnt[word] += 1

  print cnt['citizen']
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wordcount.py", line 5, in <module>
    cnt[word] += 1
KeyError: 'Fellow'
```

However, if I do this I can see that 'Fellow' keyword is in fact present.

```
  >>> text4.count('Fellow')
      24
```

Could anyone please suggest what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'Fellow'` exists in `text4` but **not** in `cnt`, which is an empty dictionary with no keys. The minimal fix is:

```
for word in text4:
       if word not in cnt:
           cnt[word] = 0
       cnt[word] += 1
```

But it's probably easier to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

cnt = Counter(text4)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Counter worked like a charm.  Would it be possible to suggest why for loop I wrote won't add 'Fellow' word ? Anything superficial or top on your head you could suggest will help.  
I will accept this answer.

Comment: Because you can't add to the value of a key that doesn't exist. Read [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).